# How can I uninstall popcorn time from Ubuntu 14.04?

Tags: uninstall

I tried `sudo apt-get remove popcorn time` but popcorn is not being recognized, then I installed the Synaptic Package Manager but it also does not recognize it, so how can i uninstall popcorn time?

Answer (score 1):

Because Popcorn Time isn't a package from the repositories, but was (presumably) installed from a Zip file, you should be able to locate the folder you unzipped into and delete its contents, then remove the folder and any desktop shortcuts.